# Translating "actually" (as in a change of mind)

Tags: traducción

There are many times I run into conversations like this:

> **Waitress**: Would you like some water?
>
> **Me**: No thanks.
>
> *She walks away for a second, then comes back*
>
> **Me**: Actually, could I get a cup of water please?

or

> **Friend**: Do you need a hand with all that heavy luggage?
>
> **Me**: No. *thinking for a few seconds...* Well, actually, would you mind carrying this bag? It is pretty heavy.

It seems like "la verdad es que" is a mouthful. Is there a short phrase common for situations like these?

Comment: In a conversational and not formal situation, you could just use "O mejor sí".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is true what Xabier has said about Pensándolo mejor. But there is another alternative that is widely used as well.

**Revision**

As per comments and thanks to CesarGon, be aware that this form is not grammatically correct and that **pensándolo mejor** should be used instead. **De hecho** is used only colloquially.

For instance:

> *De hecho*, ¿podría tomar un vaso de agua, por favor?

or

> No, ... ... [...] *de hecho* ¿te importaría ayudarme a llevar esta maleta? Es muy pesada.

Comment: _De hecho_ is also a translation of _in fact_ and _indeed_

Comment: @DavidLay Exactly, depending on context de hecho can act effectively as both or as the one needed. Powerful words! :-)

Comment: +1 this is what native spanish speaker would say.

Comment: I learned *de hecho* just four years ago and can't comprehend how I was able to make myself understood for so long without it!

Comment: -1 "De hecho" is often used in this context, but it is wrong. "De hecho" means "in fact" or "indeed", but not "actually" as in the OP.

Comment: @CesarGon I disagree with you. Do you have any sources to what you say? [De hecho as actually (University of Granada)](http://www.babylon.com/definition/de_hecho/) (Scroll down to the university dictionary definition)

Comment: @Joze: Actually, I do :-) DRAE defines "de hecho" (under "hecho") as "efectivamente" or "con eficacia y buena voluntad", i.e. "truly" or "with efficacy and good will". That's what it means. I am aware that people also use it as a rough equivalent to "pensándolo bien" (i.e. "actually" in English as per the OP), but that is not recognised by DRAE. With regard to the dictionary that you linked to, I find it a bit imprecise: its translations for "de hecho" include terms as disparate as "actually", "as it happened" and "in effect". That might reflect actual language usage, but DRAE disagrees.

Comment: @CesarGon: I see interesting. but doesn't the preposition *de* change the meaning of hecho on this context? Do you know if DRAE says something in this regard?

Comment: @Joze: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The definitions I am quoting from DRAE are for "de hecho", including "de".

Comment: @CesarGon: Thanks, I revised the answer accordingly. :-)

Answer (score 8):

"*Pensándolo mejor*" is the expression I would use on situations like these.

Examples:

> - "*Pensándolo mejor, ¿podría tomar un vaso de agua, por favor?*"
> - "*No... Bueno, pensándolo mejor, ¿te importaría llevarme esta maleta?*"

Admitted, it is a mouthful as well.

Answer (score 3):

Initially we were taught some rules, like anything ending in '-lly' became '-mente' - so in this case, 'actualmente'.  However it turns out this is a false friend - it actually (excuse pun) means 'presently/currently'.

The preferred translation is 'en realidad' as in 'in reality'.

Comment: True, but I think that, given the situations of the original question, *pensándolo mejor* is the best choice. But in general, *en realidad* should work too.

Comment: Actually English *[-ly](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ly#English)* and Spanish *[-mente](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-mente#Spanish)* are not [cognates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognate). Cognates means they have a common ancestor but the Spanish suffix comes from Latin and the English from Germanic - no relation. Spanish *-idad* and English *-ity* are an example of actual cognates. *-ly* and *-mente* on the other hand are **[false friends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend)** rather than **[false cognates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_cognate)**.

Comment: The description from the false cognates page: "False cognates are pairs of words in the same or different languages that are similar in form and meaning but have different roots. That is, they appear to be, or are sometimes considered, cognates, when in fact they are not." Oddly this seems to be almost the same wording as false friends!

Comment: Another less as to why Wikipedia alone is not such a great reference - but for now it's all I have... unless somebody would like to ask a question on [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/) (-;

Answer (score 0):

En Colombia para las situaciones planteadas se usa:

> sabe que, mas bien...

Veamos unas construcciones:

> sabe qué?, mas bien deme un vaso de agua.
>
> sabe qué?, mas bien podría llevarme el morral es que está muy pesado

Answer (score 0):

At least in Mexico, a concise way of correcting oneself in these situations is

**Siempre sí**

For example:

> ¿Le traigo un vaso de agua?
>
> **Me**: No, gracias.
>
> *after a moment's thought*
>
> Siempre sí, por favor.

> ¿Te doy una mano [con el equipaje]?
>
> No, gracias, estoy bien.... Perdón, sí, siempre sí, gracias.

This means "Yes, after all," or "Yes, actually."